# Что именно отвечает за выделение текста?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно, чтобы по клику текст копировался, но не выделялся. Не могу понять какой метод отвечает за выделение. Нагуглил, что `selectNodeContents()` выделяет текст, но это не срабатывает. Может кто то сможет подсказать ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function selectText(elementId) {
        var doc = document,
            text = doc.getElementById(elementId),
            range,
            selection;

        if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
            range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(text);
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            selection = window.getSelection();
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(text);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
    $("#linkCopy").click(function() {
        selectText(this.id);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        $('.link__url-icon').css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

```css
.link__url {
  display: flex;
}
.link__url-icon {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="link__url" id="linkCopy">https://www.google.com.ua/?hl=ru<span class="link__url-icon"><img src="./images/copy.svg"></span></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За выбирание отвечает объект `selection`, и выделяется текст после того, как ты добавил `range`.

Чтобы сбросить выделение достаточно просто удалить все выбранные интервалы, после того, как выполнится функция `document.execCommand("copy");`. Для этого можно вернуть объект `selection` из функции и очистить его непосредственно после вызова, например:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function selectText(elementId) {
    var doc = document,
      text = doc.getElementById(elementId),
      range,
      selection;

    if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
      range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(text);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
      return selection;
    }
  }
  $("#linkCopy").click(function() {
    var s = selectText(this.id);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    s.removeAllRanges();
    $('.link__url-icon').css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```css
.link__url {
  display: flex;
}

.link__url-icon {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="link__url" id="linkCopy">https://www.googwwwle.com.ua/?hl=ru<span class="link__url-icon"><img src="./images/copy.svg"></span></span>
```